# My mac is starting slow. I know login items, CleanMyMac. What else?

Tags: performance, login

My MAC has a slow start-up time (at times, 5s or more before initial black screen with Apple logo).
I am aware of login items. I have used CleanMyMac. Is there anything else I should check for?

Thank you :)

Comment: To clarify, you say 5 seconds from pressing the power button to seeing the Apple logo?

Answer (score 1):

CleanMyMac should be used with caution, or not at all. It is not recommended as a general trouble-shooting step. I would recommend [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com) , which provides you with a useful report about problems, incompatible software, and other concerns. You could edit your question to include any items that it flags. (Don't just copy and paste the whole thing, as it's quite long.)

Firstly: What's your storage like? Mechanical hard drive? How old? How full? What model of Mac, e.g. "Late 2012 13" MacBook Pro". What MacOS version?

Are you seeing slowness at any other stage? Problems that early are unlikely to be caused by user software.

Comment: ok thanks Ill try it out (wow, an app on the MacStore does anybody still use that XD)
For the model, its a Macbook Pro Retina mid-2012. The drive is empty enough for the space warning message not to appear (20+Go out of 500). Its and SSD.
Problems occur during log-in mostly. Sometimes it also slows down before allowing me to type my password.

Comment: the report doesn't say much. The Performance section is a payed feature.

Comment: [ https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25474/how-do-i-diagnose-a-slow-login?rq=1] this is a good question.
I don;t have a white screen after log-in, I have slow-downs either resuming from sleep/starting (on login window before password prompt, and sometimes after inputting passwrod (usually shorter/more bearable)