# Where is opendirectory/accounts/login information stored on macos

Tags: high-sierra, login, open-directory

I have encountered this problem of slow login ([How can I debug an extremely slow login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405048/how-can-i-debug-an-extremely-slow-login)), and have not found a solution. However, this phenomenon does not exist if I boot up into a fresh system. Since I have a backup of the system sometime ago that was working, I think that if I copy all the system files from that backup over, and then reinstall the system, the issue should be resolved. However, I don't want to copy all system files, because some of them can be outdated, some of them can be databases that are regularly updated, etc. Hence, I wonder if I can just copy over the opendirectory folders over and see if things get better (I have backups so I'm not afraid of breaking the system), but I don't know where is that information stored on disk. Where is the data files stored for opendirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stored in `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes`.