# Power Manager not working (Connection Disrupted: Unable to connect to this Mac's Scheduler at: Service unavailable via Bonjour (dns-sd))

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, dns, power-management

I had recently installed the most recent version of Power Manager, but after installing the launchdaemon/agent jobs opening the application gives me the error message "Connection Disrupted: Unable to connect to this Mac's Scheduler at: Service unavailable via Bonjour (dns-sd)"[image]
I tried various way to fix this problem:

- Follow the "learn more" [instructions](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/connection-disrupted), none of them worked;
- installing various older versions, none of them worked;
- Reading the logs: nothing interesting:

```
# log stream --style syslog --info --debug --predicate 'senderImagePath ENDSWITH "pmd"'

Filtering the log data using "senderImagePath ENDSWITH "pmd""
Timestamp                       (process)[PID]    
2021-01-17 16:05:31.083372+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Starting engine
2021-01-17 16:05:31.084062+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [60] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010015eada uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 15066
2021-01-17 16:05:31.085011+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:05:31.085267+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Trigger 2b2c21cc94f06ac079c89290949a5fb3-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 fired
2021-01-17 16:05:31.085367+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Event DE5C8F94-631E-495F-8A27-211EE3A820DB's trigger 2b2c21cc94f06ac079c89290949a5fb3-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:05:31.085470+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:05:31.085761+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Trigger 161fb7287e2eabcfc7a44b866a4fc4d8-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 fired
2021-01-17 16:05:31.085837+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Event 29ECE534-4135-403B-8762-44A6EA936BDE's trigger 161fb7287e2eabcfc7a44b866a4fc4d8-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:05:31.086039+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:05:31.086180+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Trigger 618242d5b70eda65e90390f8c54a34cc-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 fired
2021-01-17 16:05:31.086244+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Event 04A6BA3C-6F81-4FA0-91AD-201FD5DF719C's trigger 618242d5b70eda65e90390f8c54a34cc-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:05:31.086293+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:05:31.086396+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Trigger c896189e421da0e3d6518c1dd88ebbd1-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 fired
2021-01-17 16:05:31.086440+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Event 784F7AD3-5871-4904-BE8E-52701E3AAAA0's trigger c896189e421da0e3d6518c1dd88ebbd1-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:05:31.293819+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:05:31.305077+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:05:31.319013+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:05:31.340668+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:05:31.360198+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:05:31.367058+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:05:31.367187+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Starting engine
2021-01-17 16:05:31.367951+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [736] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x0000000100191269 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 221801
2021-01-17 16:05:31.368356+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [715] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001925fe uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 226814
2021-01-17 16:07:17.658311+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Stopping after signal "kSignalControllerNotificationDidSignalTERM"
2021-01-17 16:07:17.658448+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Stopping engine
2021-01-17 16:07:17.665745+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:17.669941+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:17.677982+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:17.686746+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:17.691554+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:17.698198+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1181]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x00000001001676d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.197333+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Starting engine
2021-01-17 16:07:56.197903+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [60] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d5faada uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 15066
2021-01-17 16:07:56.198552+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:07:56.198755+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Trigger 2b2c21cc94f06ac079c89290949a5fb3-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 fired
2021-01-17 16:07:56.198804+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Event DE5C8F94-631E-495F-8A27-211EE3A820DB's trigger 2b2c21cc94f06ac079c89290949a5fb3-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:07:56.198854+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:07:56.199198+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Trigger 618242d5b70eda65e90390f8c54a34cc-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 fired
2021-01-17 16:07:56.199318+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Event 04A6BA3C-6F81-4FA0-91AD-201FD5DF719C's trigger 618242d5b70eda65e90390f8c54a34cc-00-30f1f6ca32b52e28aa0c284c441e9867 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:07:56.199475+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:07:56.199690+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Trigger 161fb7287e2eabcfc7a44b866a4fc4d8-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 fired
2021-01-17 16:07:56.199760+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Event 29ECE534-4135-403B-8762-44A6EA936BDE's trigger 161fb7287e2eabcfc7a44b866a4fc4d8-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:07:56.199817+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Dequeued 0 associated triggers
2021-01-17 16:07:56.200096+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Trigger c896189e421da0e3d6518c1dd88ebbd1-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 fired
2021-01-17 16:07:56.200149+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Event 784F7AD3-5871-4904-BE8E-52701E3AAAA0's trigger c896189e421da0e3d6518c1dd88ebbd1-00-f298156b6fd41228a77b86192b98e4e5 enqueued
2021-01-17 16:07:56.578808+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d6036d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.585252+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d6036d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.594312+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d6036d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.606385+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d6036d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.614845+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d6036d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.624424+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [377] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d6036d0 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 50896
2021-01-17 16:07:56.624471+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Starting engine
2021-01-17 16:07:56.625281+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [736] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d62d269 uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 221801
2021-01-17 16:07:56.625651+0800  localhost uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd[1276]: Assertion tripped [715] 2   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd         0x000000010d62e5fe uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd + 226814
```

- Running commands provided in the [network guide](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/network.html):

```
# sudo launchctl list | grep uk\.co\.dssw\.powermanager
-   0   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.installer
118 0   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd
```

```
# lsof -i | grep uk\.co
[0|1]#
```

```
# dns-sd -B _pm._tcp.
Browsing for _pm._tcp.
DATE: ---Sun 21 Mar 2021---
19:40:41.477  ...STARTING...
// stuck here indefinitely
```

What else might have caused this behavior? How can I troubleshoot this?

Potentially relevant actions: I replaced `/var/db/dslocal` from an earlier backup due to [slow login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405048/how-can-i-debug-an-extremely-slow-login), and the issue disappears. However, I think data inconsistency might still be present but hidden because I only restored some but not all of the system preferences/data. I don't have time (yet) to do a clean reinstall.

Update:

```
# kextstat | grep -v 'com.apple.'

Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
  142    0 0xffffff7f80b4d000 0x5000     0x5000     com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower (2) 2D779840-7439-31E5-8A66-D786C3F47B75 <119 5 4 3>
  164    0 0xffffff7f83443000 0x19000    0x19000    com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfuse (3.10.4) 184072A6-C133-38A8-84A5-E8A3BC937ADD <7 5 4 3 1>
```

```
# networksetup -listallnetworkservices

An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
Belkin USB-C LAN
USB 10/100/1000 LAN
Wi-Fi
Bluetooth PAN
freevpn.pw
freevpn.pw
Parallels Host-Only #1
```

```
# pmctl log.setfilterlevel "level=debug"
No output, exit code 1

# pmctl log.filterlevel
No output, exit code 1
```

```
# dns-sd -B
Browsing for _http._tcp
DATE: ---Sun 21 Mar 2021---
20:23:49.416  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
20:23:49.611  Add        2   7 local.               _http._tcp.          jin
```

Comment: Please could you [contact the developer](https://www.dssw.co.uk/support) for help. We can help you via e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the results of the network guide commands:

```
% sudo launchctl list | grep uk\.co\.dssw\.powermanager
-   0   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.installer
118 0   uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd
```

This shows that the expected launchd jobs are present. `….installer` is a one time task used during installation and `….pmd` is the background daemon process responsible for performing your schedule.

```
% lsof -i | grep uk\.co
[0|1]#
```

This shows that there are no network sockets or ports open by any software including `uk.co` in the name. This is unexpected.

```
% dns-sd -B _pm._tcp.
Browsing for _pm._tcp.
DATE: ---Sun 21 Mar 2021---
19:40:41.477  ...STARTING...
```

This shows that no local services of type `_pm._tcp` are being advertised on your computer. This means there is no Power Manager service available.

### Networking at Fault

The lack of listening network ports and advertised service suggests the network layer is the problem.

Check what third party kernel extensions you are running:

```
kextstat | grep -v 'com.apple.'
```

This command will list lines that do not include `com.apple` from the `kextstat` command. Do you recognise the extensions shown?

Do you have a working network?

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Are *any* Bonjour/ZeroConf services available?

```
dns-sd -B
```

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to exit the above command.

### Restart `pmd`

You can force restart the [`….pmd`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/uk-co-dssw-powermanager-pmd) process using the command below:

```
sudo killall uk.co.dssw.powermanager.pmd
```

This will tear down `pmd` and launchd will dutifully relaunch the process. On launch `pmd` will attempt to set up networking and advertise its services.

Try restarting `pmd` and seeing if this restores the connection. This is not a solution but an experiment.

### Default macOS

> Potentially relevant actions: I replaced /var/db/dslocal from an earlier backup due to slow login, and the issue disappears. However, I think data inconsistency might still be present but hidden because I only restored some but not all of the system preferences/data. I don't have time (yet) to do a clean reinstall.

Given the above and that Power Manager previously worked, it suggests the replacement of `/var/db/dslocal` may be the cause of the problem.

The best solution is to install a clean copy of macOS.

### Removal and Reinstall

We do not recommend running Power Manager without the [supporting agents and applications](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/tools). Doing so means no warnings, no user interface, and many events will not perform as expected. The agents use the same mechanism as the application to talk to each other; if the application encounters disrupted connections, so will the assisting agents.

You can easily [remove Power Manager](https://dssw.co.uk/powermanager/remove/). If you then want to try again, you can re-install using the [packaged edition](https://dssw.co.uk/powermanager/dsswpowermanager.pkg). This will ensure Power Manager is correctly installed.